# JW Player: stop JW Player at last frame

Tags: jwplayer

Is there a way to stop JW Player at the last frame of the video so it won't turn into black.

I like to do this **without** specifying an image, so just with the video data.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so can you post the code?

Answer (score 2):

JW player has the duration parameter, if your video is X sexonds long specify the duration as (X-1), this is specified in the embedder javascript, just how you would specify skin or plugin or start time.

Duration : X-1,